# Stop stash embed caching file

Tags: ee2, stash

I'm using stash embed, everything inside the embed gets cached, is there any way for this not to happen?

It's a major pain when changing what's in the embed template and not seeing the change happen.

```
{!-- Main Template --}
{exp:stash:set name="_foobar_id" match="#^\S+#" default="{snippet}"}
    {snippet}
{/exp:stash:set}

{stash:embed name="_foobar"} 

{!-- Inside the stash embed  --}
<div>
   {stash:_foobar_id}
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
{stash:embed name="_foobar" replace="yes"}
```

Comment: Ha ha! You may want to remove that parameter before deploying to production. Or make the value a global variable in the config for your environment. E.g. {stash:embed name="_foobar" replace="{global:stash_replace}"}